# Why does this website look wider than its 960px?

Tags: 960.gs

http://www.zara.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/category/uk/en/zara-neu-W2012-s/317582/Coats#product=827429
 I inspect the elements of it and the body is 745 and the sidebar is something like 120 - so how can it look so wide?

thanks

Comment: All the source code is right there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It "looks wide" because the sidebar on the left is set to a fixed postion on the left of the screen so when presented on a wider monitor the sidebar always stays to the far left of the screen while the main div does some reactive sizing and stays in the center.

Comment: Cool thanks very much! Happy New year!